# How to directly access a class variable value after a call to a function, i.e. class.function().value_from_class

Tags: python

I have a class that has a function inside, which updates instance variables. In this case, the class does dynamic calculations. Here's a trivial example, where it defines the x and v vectors, and has a move() function to update the position over a time interval dt.

```
import numpy as np
class Dynamics():
     def __init__(self,x0,v0):
         self.X=np.array(x0)
         self.V=np.array(v0)
     def move(self,dt):
         self.X=self.X+self.V*dt
```

Now I could call this as follows to start at the origin moving at speed 1 m/s to the right:

```
>>> particle=Dynamics([0,0,0],[1,0,0])
>>> particle.move(2)
>>> print particle.X
[2,0,0]
```

But I would rather be able to access X directly from the move() call:

```
>>> particle.move(2).X
```

However when I do this, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'X'
```

Comment: You could `return self`; this would be a step towards a "fluent interface".

Answer (score 1):

> which updates class variables

Those are actually *instance variables*

> But I would rather be able to access X directly from the move() call

I don't see a clear reason why you want to do this, but you can `return self` rather than the default action of any Python function of `return None`.

```
def move(self,dt):
     self.X=self.X+self.V*dt
     return self
```

Now your code should work